# Setting up a recurring subscription service for an ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, paypal

I have an ASP.NET website that is similar to Yellow Pages in functionality and I want to offer a recurring subscription service to users that enables their business profiles to be priority listed, or brought to the top if they are subscribed. Each user has a "SubscriptionLevel" integer tied to their account on the database side and I simply need to modify that field depending on what subscription service they select. Are there any C# libraries out there I can use to set this up quick? I would prefer users to pay through PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do this. There's lots of 'out of the box' subscription services but if you are here I'm assuming you are a developer so why not just integrate with the API. Paypal provides their [recurring payment API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/)

Keep in mind you can test this easily inside of their [sandbox environment](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/)